# Messed up USB stick doesn't show in blkid

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, formatting, storage, blocking

I was playing around with a USB stick (booting archlinux with `qemu` off of it and trying to perform an installation on the same stick at the same time -- brave, I know, but I was just messing around).

Now, after failing to boot and install at the same time, it seems I have sort of messed up my stick. What I think happened is that I used `cfdisk` to wipe everything on it and create one big partition, but formatting it then failed, so now there's a big partition with no filesystem.

Just to make it clear: **I'm not worried for my stick**, I know I can recover it at any point.

What I find intriguing is that after plugging the stick into my computer (using Ubuntu), there's no (terminal) way to find out what block device (`/dev/sdx`) it has associated. The only way I could determine that was with GParted:

[image: GParted showing /dev/sdc]

But `blkid` shows the following:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="12F695CFF695B387" LABEL="System Reserved" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="A0BAA6EABAA6BC62" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="546aec8b-9ad6-4571-b07a-adba63e25820" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="2a8b82d8-6c6e-4053-a446-bab970d93d7c" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb3: UUID="7cbede7d-c930-4e59-9d1b-01f2d79bd092" TYPE="ext4"
```

No trace of `/dev/sdc`. My question is: if I didn't have a graphical interface (to use GParted), how would I have known which block device is my stick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several methods to discover a device node.

- Examine kernel output with the `dmesg` command.
- Try `fdisk -l`.  (This should spit out partition tables for all attached drives.)
- Examine the output of `lshw -short` (*ls hardware*), or use similar commands like ***lspci*** or ***lsusb***, depending on what you know about the device you seek.  If ***lshw*** isn't available on your system, install the *lshw* package to get it.
- Examine the ***sys*** filesystem manually.  (For example, use `ls /sys/block/` or `ls -d /sys/block/s*` and look for unfamiliar device names.)
- Examine the ***/dev*** directory manually.  (For example, use `ls /dev/sd*` and look for unfamiliar device names.)

As I understand it, ***blkid*** only looks at partitions, not raw drive devices.  (This is probably an oversimplication.)  The ***lshw*** command and similar are better for obtaining direct hardware information.

Comment: You can also use `testdisk` to recreate partition table pointing to filesystems found by testdisk.

Comment: I knew about most of these but didn't know I could use them in this way. Thanks.

Comment: This is a nice answer but I can not understand how to use it to `sudo fsck` onto my device since its partitions don't show (and for example `ls /dev/sdb*` only shows `/dev/sdb`).